# How can I add model in database Mysql in django without problems and with encoding utf-8?

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8

I have project on Django with Mysql. Databases was imported from another project by using command "python manage.py inspectdb"
Everything worked correctly with english and russian symbols.
I added easy model and migrated it. This model workes correctly only with english symbols, but with russian symbols doesn't work

Error:
"Exception Type:    OperationalError
Exception Value:
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x94\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBC...' for column 'title' at row 1")"

I think that is the problem with encoding.

Mysql encoding was latin1 and changed to utf-8, but error was not resolved.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

PLease help me to use russian symbols in this model.

Another question: this model was migrated, I can see it in django administration, but I can't find the table with this model in mysql in database in all tables. What I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were expecting `Дим...`.

Django needs

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'utf8',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    },
}
```

(or utf8mb4)

> Mysql encoding was latin1 and changed to utf-8

How did you make the change?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on one of the tables.  And do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for a small sample that should be showing Cyrillic.  There may be worse problems at hand, and other things that need changing.  There are (at least) two ways to fix the schema, one way is 'correct', the rest make things *worse*.